# Elementary graph theory questions (periodicity and strongly connected components)

Tags: graph-theory

Just going through some graph theory concepts and I have two elementary questions which must be pretty trivial (but sometimes what seems trivial to me turns out to be wrong, so I'd be happy if someone could confirm that the following are indeed true):

> (1) A periodic graph cannot self-loops - because self-loops are cycles of length 1.

Each graph $G$ can be split into strongly connected components and the 'rest of the world' $R$ (nodes in no connected component but with possible links to connected components).

> (2) If $G$ is undirected, $R$ can only consist of isolated nodes (nodes with links to no other node).

Comment: Could you expand on $(1)$? I'm not sure what it's asking.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aperiodic_graph

Comment: Ah, the question looks like "A periodic graph" rather than "Aperiodic graph". 
For $1$ it seems that an aperiodic graph can have self-loops, since the definition asks for an integer $>1$ that divides the cycle lengths. 

For $2$, assume $R$ contains a non-isolated vertex. Then, that vertex forms a connected component of size $ \geq 2$ in an undirected graph.

Comment: @SanicHodgeheg A periodic graph is one that is not aperiodic, dude. Standard concept in graph theory.

Comment: Your "disproof" of 2 seems to be wrong, too. You make a connected component out of $R$, but then $R$ does not satisfy its definition, which is: **not** to be a connected component.

Comment: @mathse I was looking at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Periodic_graph_(graph_theory), sorry.

I assume that $R$ can contain non-isolated vertices and arrive at a contradiction, so $R$ can only contain isolated vertices. Let me know if I'm making some obvious mistake, which is very possible.

Comment: @SanicHodgeheg The user stated the Wikipedia definition of "aperiodic". To get the definition for "periodic", you need to negate the definition of "aperiodic". For (2), you make a very gross mistake: $R$ is **defined** as "nodes in no connected component". Now, given that you have constructed $R$ as a connected component, you arrived at a contradiction. Hence, your assumption must have been wrong.

Comment: @SanicHodgeheg With all respect, but you seem to have little knowledge of graph theory, so why do you confuse a user who obviously needs help from an expert?

Comment: To understand your error in (2): A directed graph can be split into strongly connected components and some group of nodes $R$: $(C_1,\ldots,C_K,R)$ , where $R$ is not a strongly connected component. Now, you claim that you can transform $R$ into a strongly connected component $C_{K+1}$. But when you achieve this, $R$ no longer satisfies its definition.